How can I play content with DAI and preroll Content in Video JS and React JS
I have content, in which I have to play pre-roll ads first and then I have to play the DAI content,
But I am not sure how to achieve this, this is working using HLS but not working with video.js
I am using video js and Google IMA SDK for this task
"video.js": "^7.20.1"
"videojs-ima": "^2.1.0",
"videojs-contrib-ads": "^6.9.0",

I would be grateful if any suggestions can be provided on this
I have tried adding both with the video js player object but am getting an error as added in the attachment.
Sample Data used :-
daiKey: "c-rArva4ShKVIAkNfy6HUQ",
adTagUrl: "https://pubads.g.doubleclick.net/gampad/ads?iu=/21775744923/external/single_ad_samples&sz=640x480&cust_params=sample_ct%3Dlinear&ciu_szs=300x250%2C728x90&gdfp_req=1&output=vast&unviewed_position_start=1&env=vp&impl=s&correlator=",


